# HTML password input still listening to key bindings while other inputs ignore the bindings

Tags: html, reactjs, input, key-bindings

I am working on a legacy react app. There are keybindings in the project. For this example let's say when a user clicks "F", then the the app goes to full screen. The issue is that this keybinding is active for some input fields like email and password.

When I type into a non labeled input field, and i type "F", nothing happens, like:

```
<input
      value={this.state.firstName}
      placeholder="First Name"
      name="firstName"
      required
      onChange={(event) => {return this.handleChange(event, 'firstName', event.target.value)}}/>
```

However if I have email or password as the label, then when i type "F", it goes full screen like

```
<input
      value={this.state.password}
      placeholder="Password"
      name="password"
      label="password"
      required
      onChange={(event) => {return this.handleChange(event, 'password', event.target.value)}}/>
```

```
  private handleChange = (event: any, key: string, value: string) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState<never>({ [key]: value } as Partial<LoginFormState>);
    }
```

How can i stop this behavior on password and email without undoing all of the key bindings and rebinding them?

Comment: could you provide handleChange code bloc

Comment: Good call, just did!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `event.preventDefault()` ?

```
<input
  value={this.state.password}
  placeholder="Password"
  name="password"
  label="password"
  required
  onChange={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    return this.handleChange(event, 'password', event.target.value);
  }}
/>
```

I'm not sure it's a clean solution though, you might want to provide more details for a better solution.

I just noticed, you should not pass `event.target.value` as an argument, since you already pass `event`. You can just access `event.target.value` directly into `this.handleChange`.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I did have the `event.preventDefault();` set.